# Event handling across views/forms (MVP-VM framework)

Tags: c#, events, architecture, mvp

Architechture, Flow of events -

**Type 1**

1. MainForm - Creates presenter
2. The presenter then creates and display the view.

**Type 2 - Grid**

1. MainForm - Create a grid-presenter
2. Every Row in a grid is linked to a detail form - DetailPresenter
3. On double-click, the grid-presenter creates a detail presenter, and then the detail presenter then creates and display the view.

The problem  - The views need to refresh or the presenter needs to reload the data. For eg there are two forms A and B. When both are open at the same time, Any change in A should trigger a refresh in B. There is also a situation when a Type 1 form should refresh the grid.

I want to avoid the solution where main form keeps a reference of every presenter and triggers the necessary events. As of now I can only think of static events. I want to solve the higher problem of messaging across views. Any better solution?

Comment: To avoid coupling, you might want to check the [Event Aggregator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices) construct. Lots of frameworks have some implementations of event aggregation (Caliburn.Micro, to mention one that I use frequently)

Comment: Thanks, really useful. As I cannot use any frameworks, I found a simpler implementation that might get the job done. http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/development/design-patterns/event-aggregator-implementation What do you think? Any drawbacks in using the code as is?

Comment: Looks clean and simple, if it fulfills your requirements - go for it. Or you can peek into other implementations in the frameworks themselves - here's the [Caliburn.Micro's one](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7e9f69969a0e#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/EventAggregator.cs) (just to follow the example I gave last time) or the Mvvm Light Messenger somewhere in the [MVVM Light Source](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0f4486b50609). Either way, it's all up to you :)

Comment: thanks, if you can move your comments into reply, I will mark as answer and close this topic. Event Aggregator is exactly the pattern that solves my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclosing the comments into the answer:

What's needed here is the [Event Aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343980/event-aggregator-implementation-sample-best-practices) pattern.

As you suggested, the [simple messenger implementation](http://www.minddriven.de/index.php/technology/development/design-patterns/event-aggregator-implementation) should work quite nice, if you want to roll out your own, you can always peek into the [Caliburn.Micro implementation](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7e9f69969a0e#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/EventAggregator.cs) or Mvvm Light Messenger in the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0f4486b50609) for inspiration.